# How to get a DevExpress grid to fill a user control

Tags: asp.net, datagrid, user-controls, devexpress

I am quite new to ASP.NET development so I am unsure of how to do this without hardcoding the value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the ASPxGridView to occupy a container space by width, set the control's Width property to 100%.  This trick won't work for the height.  Please note, the ASPxGridView is an XHTML compatible control and this standard does not support setting the height property yo 100%.  Also, I should tell you that usually the grid's height is defined by its content.  I.e. if you are planning to show 10 records per page, the grid's height will be identified by the height of these 10 rows + height of the column headers pane, height of the pager and other elements (footer, group panel...).  If you want to set the control's height directly, I would suggest that you activate the vertical scrollbar (Settings.ShowVerticalScrollbar = true and specify the Settings.VerticallScrollableHeight property.  This property will allow you to define the height of the of the scrollable part (rows). I hope, this information will be helpful to you.